# Cannot achieve the same result as the tutorial, mine had some shading issues

Tags: modeling, shaders, bevel

i am following some tutorial and i followed every step in the tut, but mine mesh came with a lot of shading problems. The edge are not smooth at all.
Can someone help me out ? I set the smooth shading already and bevel modifier as well. Even tweaking the settings cannot fix it.
[image]
[image]

Comment: so which one is your version? what tutorial are you following? could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: The nasty one(second) is mine. And i am following Creative shrimp's hard surface modeling tut, which i purchased from his website. I will share my file now.

Comment: Having difficulty in uploading blender files. I tried blender-Exchange, it always fail..

Comment: you need to copy paste the url of this page before uploading